# Talend - ESB - SOAP webservice

Tags: esb, talend

I need to realize a Talend ESB project that basically have an input SOAP WS ,based on a parameter it needs to execute different subjobs.

This is the SOAP Request

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://www.talend.org/service/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:test_callOperationRequest>
         <user>user</user>
         <password>psw/password>
         <id_customer>test ESB</id_customer>
         <query>test mirror quality</query>
         <command>JOB1</command>
      </ser:test_callOperationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I'd like to call specific subjob based on "command" parameter (i.e.:JOB1).

This is my actual project structure:
[image]

Any suggestion on right Talend component to use? Shall I include Routes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option "Use dynamic job" of tRunJob component :

[image]

Once you check the option, you get a field called "Context job", in which you specify the name of the child job you want to run, from a list of jobs that you choose by clicking "..." next to the Job field.

You can connect `tJavaRow_1` to `tRunJob_1` by a main flow, and in the Context job field, specify the incoming flow's column containing the name of the job to run (in my example it's `row2.JobToRun`).
The corresponding childjob is then called for each incoming row.

Comment: That's was I looking for! Thank you!